# Python: changing decimals into integer from a text file and adding value in empty column

Tags: python, text, integer, decimal

I have multiple text files containing similar entries as below example:

```
Col. 1: 
Col. 2: 
Col. 3: 
Col. 4: 
Col. 5: 
Col. 6: 
Col. 7: 
Col. 8: 
Col. 9: 
Col. 10: 
Col. 11: 
Col. 12:
Col. 13: 
,1,1895,448.77322857065207,261.6451302661571,487.87504072093765,644.5008280767337,137.91802608912175,7585.957722436398,375.6421839231339,392.7870738998909,4966.1022623875415,168.17
,2,1895,407.34438288198265,217.82070357284303,437.7885530091468,365.9530981375767,103.95702443746582,5691.412698610184,214.51535347696034,217.7204092533743,3076.675303629703,142.79
etc......
```

with this data what I want to achieve is:

1. convert the decimal numbers into integer, all the numbers should be a integer
2. I have multiple text files where a specific number should be added in first column just before
   the ',' leaving rest of the files as it is
3. It should start writing from line 14 skipping lines above it

I am beginner in Python can do simpler stuff but this looks beyond my capabilities. Anyone who could help me would be much appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: It's not clear what the output is supposed to look like. If you could include the sample output for your sample input that would be helpful. I would suggest reading up on the pandas module https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/getting_started/index.html and in particular the `read_csv` and `write_csv` functions.

Comment: If you have a specific issue while solving this yourself you can ask here with your code.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. The output that i am expecting is below:  
Col. 1: 
Col. 2: 
Col. 3: 
Col. 4: 
Col. 5: 
Col. 6: 
Col. 7: 
Col. 8: 
Col. 9: 
Col. 10: 
Col. 11: 
Col. 12:
Col. 13: 
1,1,1895,449,262,488,645,138,7586,376,393,4966,168
1,2,1895,407,218,438,366,104,5691,215,218,3077,143

Answer (score 0):

Because this is a text file, we can read it with python's functions. After getting the text, we can split it by the colon. This will return with a list full of text with everything between the colons. The last list element is what we want to edit. Then we can further split this by commas, and we now have a list of numbers. Loop through them, get rid of all unneeded text stuff, and round them and turn them into integers, and it returns a list of pure integers. It then just pops the fixed integer list back into the value list and puts itself back together.
Code:

```
text = open("file.txt", "r").read()

value_list = text.split(':')

values = value_list[-1].split(',')

new_value_list = []

for value in values:
    value = value.replace('\n','')
    value = value.replace(' ','')
    
    value = float(value)
    value = round(value)
    
    value = str(value)
    
    new_value_list.append(value)
    
fixed_values = (','.join(new_value_list))

value_list[-1] = fixed_values
value_list[-2] = value_list[-2] + "\n"

fixed_file = ''.join(value_list)
print(fixed_file)
```

file.txt (I changed it a bit so use this format)

```
Col. 1: 
Col. 2: 
Col. 3: 
Col. 4: 
Col. 5: 
Col. 6: 
Col. 7: 
Col. 8: 
Col. 9: 
Col. 10: 
Col. 11: 
Col. 12:
Col. 13: 
1,1895,448.77322857065207,261.6451302661571,487.87504072093765,644.5008280767337,137.91802608912175,7585.957722436398,375.6421839231339,392.7870738998909,4966.1022623875415,168.17
,2,1895,407.34438288198265,217.82070357284303,437.7885530091468,365.9530981375767,103.95702443746582,5691.412698610184,214.51535347696034,217.7204092533743,3076.675303629703,142.79
```

(Assuming the text file is in the same directory and has the name file.txt)

THIS IS NOT A VERY GOOD SCRIPT TO USE. It brute forces a lot of stuff, but it at least gets the job done, so check over it and fix it up. But I think if you keep these files in the same format it should work every time.

FYI: It does not have to have exactly 13 lines of 'column:' because the script splits by the last colon. Also, you can do whatever you want with the value in the for loop, and you can do whatever you want with the fixed_value list. I just shoved it back into the original string, but if you want to make a whole other column, replace

```
value_list[-1] = fixed_values
value_list[-2] = value_list[-2] + "\n"
```

with

```
value_list.append(fixed_values)
value_list[-2] = value_list[-2] + "\n"
```